# check exist external XML with short time

Tags: xml, load, external, fopen

I need solve my problem with check external XML file in short time.
If i use function `if (fopen($sxml[$looppocet], "r"))` and I have more XML files forexample 15 so this take a very long time and I need config execution time but this is very bad solved.
I need check one file if this file is exist then continue go in my cycle if not so print my error and next step next file too.

Please how can I solve this problem?

Comment: [`is_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) / [`file_exists()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)?

Comment: file/exists() is only for local files but I need check external file forexample (http://domain/fresh.xml)

Comment: If you can't modify that external server, then I doubt there will be any "short time" solution locally, as I think the main bottleneck would be the time spent communicating with the external server, whatever method you use.

Comment: I cant modify because that isn't server but external hardware and I read values from this hardware with use his XML file.. I have 20 this hardwares in my country and I need read values from all this hardwares. But problem is... If someone harware is shutdown forexample for power lost so my website wait 30sec for this XML. If shutdows more hardwares so that is big problem for looong time loaading and errors for missing XMLs :(

Comment: @RastislavNad' That's the problem. The bottleneck is the time spent communicating, which is generally not avoidable. You can try to cache the external XML on your server periodically, if that's possible and reasonable.

Comment: Or Can I check some ping on this hardware with PHP? And can this solve faster?

Comment: You still have to wait for the timeout of `ping`. I guess that may be faster, but you'll have to test out to make sure.

Comment: Its faster... change time from 30sec on 2 sec on one hardware

Comment: Now you can answer your question :) Post your solution below and accept it so other may benefit from your idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is... Im checked ping on external device with use this function.

```
function icmpChecksum($data){
if (strlen($data)%2)
$data .= "\x00";

$bit = unpack('n*', $data);
$sum = array_sum($bit);

while ($sum >> 16)
$sum = ($sum >> 16) + ($sum & 0xffff);

return pack('n*', ~$sum);
}
// Making the package
$type= "\x08";
$code= "\x00";
$checksum= "\x00\x00";
$identifier = "\x00\x00";
$seqNumber = "\x00\x00";
$data= "Scarface";
$package = $type.$code.$checksum.$identifier.$seqNumber.$data;
$checksum = icmpChecksum($package); // Calculate the checksum
$package = $type.$code.$checksum.$identifier.$seqNumber.$data;
// And off to the sockets
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 1);
socket_set_option ( $socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array("sec"=>1, "usec"=>0) );
socket_connect($socket, 192.168.0.1, null);
$startTime = microtime(true);
socket_send($socket, $package, strLen($package), 0);
if (false === (@socket_read($socket, 255))) {       
            echo "Harddware is OFF--->";
    } else {
            echo "Harddware is ON--->";
           }
```

If Im use classic ping with shell function so that was total unstable for me :)